# timezone_name_from_abbr is not working in php

Tags: php

I am working in PHP. I want to get my timezone, **Asia/Dhaka**, from offset **6x60x60 = 21600**. I have tried with `timezone_name_from_abbr("", 21600, false);`
But it's not working. I'm getting false.
What can I do now?

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation mentions a bug in that function : [PHP timezone_name_from_abbr](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.timezone-name-from-abbr.php#86928)

You can write a function to parse the result of `timezone_abbreviations_list()` yourself :

```
/* Takes a GMT offset and returns a timezone name */
function tz_offset_to_name($offset, $dst)
{
    $results = array();
    
    $abbrarray = timezone_abbreviations_list();
    foreach ($abbrarray as $abbr)
    {
        foreach ($abbr as $city)
        {
             if ($city['offset'] == $offset and $city['dst'] == $dst)
             {
                 $results[] = $city['timezone_id'];
             }
        }
    }

    return $results;
}
```

It gives the correct result :

```
$offset = 6*60*60 ;
$tz = timezone_name_from_abbr("", $offset, false);
var_dump($tz); // false

$tz = tz_offset_to_name($offset, false);
print_r($tz);
```

```
(
    [0] => Asia/Aqtobe
    [1] => Asia/Almaty
    [2] => Asia/Dacca
    [3] => Asia/Dhaka
    [4] => Asia/Thimbu
    [5] => Asia/Thimphu
    [6] => Asia/Dacca
    [7] => Asia/Dhaka
    [8] => Asia/Dushanbe
    [9] => Asia/Bishkek
    [10] => Asia/Hovd
    [11] => Indian/Chagos
    [12] => Asia/Bishkek
    [13] => Asia/Qyzylorda
    [14] => Asia/Krasnoyarsk
    [15] => Asia/Novokuznetsk
    [16] => Asia/Colombo
    [17] => Antarctica/Mawson
    [18] => Asia/Novosibirsk
    [19] => Asia/Novokuznetsk
    [20] => Asia/Omsk
    [21] => Asia/Qyzylorda
    [22] => Asia/Aqtau
    [23] => Asia/Samarkand
    [24] => Asia/Tashkent
    [25] => Asia/Oral
    [26] => Antarctica/Vostok
    [27] => Asia/Kashgar
    [28] => Asia/Urumqi
    [29] => Asia/Yekaterinburg
    [30] => 
)
```